# passing primitive data type to a function in c++

Tags: c++

I want to implement a function like this

```
double d = string_to("1223.23",double);
int i = string_to("1223",int);
bool d = string_to("1",bool);
```

How can I pass the `bool`, `int`, `double` data type to implement this in c++?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Types line `int`, `double` and `bool` can only be passed as [template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) parameters.

You can use templates like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

template<typename DataType>
DataType string_to(const std::string& s)
{
    DataType d;
    std::istringstream(s) >> d; // convert string to DataType
    return d;
}

int main()
{
    double d = string_to<double>("1223.23");
    int i = string_to<int>("1223");
    bool b = string_to<bool>("1");

    std::cout << "d: " << d << '\n';
    std::cout << "i: " << i << '\n';
    std::cout << "b: " << b << '\n';
}
```

As an alternative you can pass your numeric types by reference and rely on function overloading to select the correct function:

```
void string_to(const std::string& s, double& d)
{
    d = std::stod(s);
}

void string_to(const std::string& s, int& i)
{
    i = std::stoi(s);
}

void string_to(const std::string& s, bool& b)
{
    std::istringstream(s) >> std::boolalpha >> b;
}

int main()
{
    double d;
    int i;
    bool b;

    string_to("1223.23", d);
    string_to("1223", i);
    string_to("true", b);

    std::cout << "d: " << d << '\n';
    std::cout << "i: " << i << '\n';
    std::cout << "b: " << b << '\n';
}
```

Also you could templatize the second method (an exercise for the reader).

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to do this, you can pass the type by using the typeid operator.

E.g. double d = string_to("1223.23", typeid(double));

Using the library functions atoi, stod would make more sense.

If you're aiming to write more uniform code then you could write a Converter object and use method overloading to get automatic selection by type.

```
class Converter 
{
public:
    void fromString(double& value, const char* string);
    void fromString(int& value, const char* string);
    void fromString(long& value, const char* string);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way that uses tag dispatching. You can compile and run this example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>


namespace detail {

    // declare the concept of conversion from a string to something

    template<class To>
    To string_to(const std::string&);

    // make some models of the concept

    template<>
    int string_to<int>(const std::string& s) {
        return atoi(s.c_str());
    }

    template<>
    double string_to<double>(const std::string& s) {
        return atof(s.c_str());
    }

    template<>
    std::string string_to<std::string>(const std::string& s) {
        return s;
    }

    // ... add more models here

}

// define the general case of conversion from string with a model tag
// note the unused parameter allows provision of a model that is never used
// thus the model will in all likelihood be optimised away
template<class To>
To string_to(const std::string& from, const To& /* model_tag is unused */)
{
    // dispatch to correct conversion function using the To type
    // as a dispatch tag type
    return detail::string_to<To>(from);
}

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    // examples
    int a = string_to("100", a);
    double b = string_to("99.9", b);
    const string s = string_to("Hello", s);

    cout << s << " " << a << " " << b << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Hello 100 99.9
```